# How can I test my code against different environments with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am working on a project that carries out actions against different versions of IIS depending on what is locally installed.  I thought I had read that you could debug in different Virtual machine environments through Visual Studio 2010 if you have the VM's available.

I am working in a Windows 7 environment but need to test my code against a Windows 2003 / IIS 6 environment.  Am only limited to creating that environment (VM and all necessary development tools) and testing my code locally?

My question wasn't as clear - I want all the benefits of running in debug mode that I would get if I was developing directly in that environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my own answer:

**Remote Debugging of a Project Built Locally**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6by8d2.aspx

Comment: Yup - you found it :) "Remote Debugging"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can automate it, but you can remotely debug from visual studio to code running on another machine. If I remember correctly, the trick is (if you're on a domain network) to log into both machines with the same user account (I did this in an active directory networked type environment).

It may have changed in 2010 (I'm on 2008 today), but start the debug instance on the remote machine, then from the VS debug menu, choose "Attach to Process", change the transport to "Remote" and enter in the machine name.

You should then be able to attach to the process, and set breakpoints and debug as you would any other session.

Comment: So what do you call this process of "running your debug code against another remote machine" on your network?  All my searches keep turning up "Lab Management" which is not what it sounds like I need.